# how pass variable from a class to another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the numOfItems set in this class and I want to use it in another class AddToCart, but I cant pass the variable successfully.. here is a sample code, please how can I do this, I cannot seem to figure it out, What I want to know is the best way to pass data after I have setState to the other class..

````
  static int numOfItems = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        buildOutlineButton(
          icon: Icons.remove,
          press: () {
            if(numOfItems > 1){
              setState(() {
                numOfItems--;
              });
            }
          },
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin / 2),
          child: Text(
            //"01",
            numOfItems.toString().padLeft(2, "0"),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
          ),
        ),
        buildOutlineButton(
            icon: Icons.add,
            press: () {
              setState(() {
                numOfItems++;
              });
            }),
      ],
    );
  }

  SizedBox buildOutlineButton({IconData icon, Function press}) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      child: OutlineButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        onPressed: press,
        child: Icon(icon),
      ),
    );
  }
}```


here is the second class where I want to use the numOfItems in the second class, how can I access the variable in this class.

```class AddToCart extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddToCart({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPaddin),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:kDefaultPaddin),
            height:50,
            width: size.width * 0.3,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color:primaryColorDark),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                "assets/icons/add_to_cart.svg", color: primaryColorDark,), //svgPicture.asser
              onPressed: () {
                // on press of the cart button
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              height:50,
              child: FlatButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)
                ),
                color: primaryColor,
                onPressed: (){
                  addProductToCart(context);

                },
                child: Text(
                    "Buy Now".toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void addProductToCart(BuildContext context) {
   
    String quantityToSend = numOfItems
  }
}
}```

What I want to know is the best way to pass data after I have setState to the other class..
````

Comment: This doc shows how to send data to another screen: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: AddToCart is another screen, or is it another widget you are going to show on the screen? If it is another screen you can use the link provided in the first comment, if not, and you are talking of another widget, just generate another constructor parameter con AddToCart to receive the int numOfItems and you can use it inside.

Comment: yes it is another widget but, I created a widget folder seprately, so each widget are in different .dart file, which I just call in my mainPage..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `constructor` to pass variable 
Example: 
Screen1:

```
class _TabsPageState extends State<TabsPage> {
  int args = 3;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Text('Navigate to home', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          onPressed: () {
            print('123');
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Tab2Page(args)));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screen2:

```
class Tab2Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final int args;

  Tab2Page(this.args);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(args.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only this variable " If it widget " just use the name of class `x` and then `.` then `the name of static variable`

i.e `x.numOfItems`

If this a another screen and you want to pass the data to this screen you can do it like this

```
class SecondScreen{
var anyVariable;
XScreen(this.anyVariable);
.......
......
}

onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondScreen(anyVariable :numOfItems),
          ),
        );
      },
```